# How to get Xcode build onto Apple app connect?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I just successfully ran Xcode for an app I am making and the build said it was successful with the hammer graphic on the screen, even though it stated there were some errors. I used the built-in simulator to check the app and everything is working fine. The question I have is, how do I get this app build onto app connect? I have logged my account info into Xcode and when I go to the Organizer screen I can see the name of my app, but nothing in the archives. This app is already on the app store, so I am creating the 2.0 build for it and have all of that ready on the App store.

How can I get my app build loaded into the app store so that I can release for review?

Comment: Have you archived the project?

Comment: No idea, I guess not. This will be the first time I finished an app with xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Set destination scheme to: generic iOS device

Archive project by going to: Product > Archive

Answer (score 0):

Hope these will help you :)

[Uploading App to Appstore Connect](https://codewithchris.com/submit-your-app-to-the-app-store/)

[Updating already existing App on Appstore](https://help.swiftic.com/hc/en-us/articles/201701881-Update-Your-App-on-the-Apple-App-Store)